# Memory Exception even after maxRequestLength set to maximum

Tags: sql, asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-2.0

I am getting 865831 records with 33 fields from local db, and I set `maxRequestLength="2097151"` and I am still getting MemoryException error. Is there any thing else I can do to increase memory? My application is in asp.net 2.0, vb